# backpack laravel crud custom column

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I have a task - insert a custom column in one of our admin pages, where I can to call method from Model for each entry, generated by backpack CRUD generator.
I have found in official documentations statement that looks like what I need here:

https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/v3.0/docs/crud-columns-types#section-roll-your-own

But there is nothing about how to implement this in the controller right way.
So I have tried to do just like this

Controller:

```
$status = [
        'label' => 'Status',
        'name'  => 'status',
        'type'  => 'text'
    ];
$this->crud->addColumn($status);
```

and as mentinoned in documentation, I have create my own blade file in

```
resources\views\vendor\backpack\crud\columns
```

Here it is:

```
{{-- status --}}
<td>{{ $entry->isBlocked }}</td>
```

Where isBlocked is method in my Model. I have an error about database and nothing is working.
Please say is it even possible to do what I wnat and if it is - please say how to do it right way both in view and controller

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Let's check your code

```
 $status = [
        'label' => 'Status',
        'name'  => 'isBlocked', // your column name 
        'type'  => 'status' // your blade name, e.g status.blade.php
      ];

$this->crud->addColumn($status);
```

and inside status.blade.php

```
{{-- status --}}
<td>{{ $entry->{$column['name'] }}</td>
```

Any question, please comment

Comment: Hey! Thankyou foy your answer! Your suggestion lloks logocal and right way but after implementing it I still have an error
    "DataTables warning: table id=crudTable - Ajax error. For more 
    information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7"